# What place am I?

Tags: riddle, rhyme, history

> I was **once** part of an ocean, more specifically a sea,
>   my only natural border, is a river sharing a name of what was once a legal enemy.

### Hint

> I am in North America

### Hint2

> The river borders something with the same name

### Hint3

> I am in the great plains

Comment: Is the hint really necessary? The question title itself designates the answer as a place.

Comment: I changed it to something more specific.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Is it

> Kansas
>  Kansas was covered by the Permian Sea during the Permian era.
>  It's only natural border is the Missouri river, and Missouri was a recognized Confederate state, but never taken over by the Confederates, which makes it an enemy only legally speaking.

Comment: I'm going to say I think it's this one. I was just coming to post here. [And this](https://www.nps.gov/tapr/learn/nature/geology-at-the-preserve.htm).

Comment: @SendersReagent Thanks for that extra bit...adding to the answer

Comment: I wasn't sure if that's okay here, but I didn't see anything in the tour and such. I figured if you weren't sure and you already answered what I was planning to answer, should be fine?

Comment: @SendersReagent It's fine...a lot of the answers here are pieced together from contributions of different people.

Comment: There isn't any justification why this answer is correct and mine isn't, since both meet all conditions specified.

Comment: @Orch I don't think it is worth posting a puzzle if I have to look for every possible answer after all I would have to do more work the than those who guess and it would make the answer way to easy to figure out or extremely complex. I do understand that you spent time on your guess but if you are guessing you should be prepared for your answer to be incorrect. And if the answer is already there do I really need to provide more relative information to divide the incorrect with what I originally planned to be correct?

Comment: @Darrius It's understandable if there are other answers to your puzzle that are correct that you didn't consider, and if that's the case you should simply acknowledge they are correct as well.

Answer (score 4):

> "The Mexicans and Indians on the borders of Mexico are in the habit of calling any river, the waters of which have a red appearance, 'Rio Colorado', or Red river", observed R.B. Marcy in 1853.

---

> **Oklahoma**'s only natural border is with Texas at the [Red River of the South](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red_River_of_the_South), its name given to us by "Mexicans and Indians," and at least part of the state [was once a sea](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Western_Interior_Seaway).[image]

Comment: Do what is the enemy? Is it "The South"?

Comment: @SendersReagent - The [enemies](http://definitions.uslegal.com/e/enemy-of-the-united-states/) were "Mexicans and Indians."

Comment: Hmm... Well, that doesn't make  "Colorado" a "legal enemy," just what said enemies call it. Curious to see what says!

Comment: Ohhh, I get it. Named *by* an enemy.

Comment: You were super close. The next hint should give it away.

Comment: @SendersReagent Totally messed up there. Probably should have put "sharing a name of" rather than "named by".

Answer (score 3):

> Nebraska

Explanation:

> It was once part of a sea, has a natural border (a river) that shares the name with the state it borders and the name comes from the Sioux.  And of course, it's part of north america and the great plains.

Comment: Can you explain why you think that? Answers without explanation are generally deleted. (Also, welcome to Puzzling!)

Comment: @Deusovi I think you put this comment on the wrong answer

Comment: @Darrius: Check the timestamps and edit history: it had no explanation when I commented.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a perfect answer, but is it:

> Imperial Valley, California

Explanation:

> Imperial Valley was once part of the Gulf of California, also called the Vermilion Sea. It is bordered by the Colorado River. "Colorado" comes from the Spanish language, and both the Mexicans and Spanish were at a time an enemy of the United States.

Comment: AZ and NV would fit the description if Colorado answers the second part.

Comment: Close not what I am looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Answer:

> [Colorado Piedmont](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Colorado_Piedmont)

This follows everything in the puzzle.
Explanation:

> This is in Great plains and was once part of an ocean. Colorado river border.

Comment: You missed out on the hint3. And i can't really find to much information on this so i can't tell you how close you were.